# Pull from remote repo without a commit history?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am working on a project on a gitHub with my friends, and I want to know if there is any way we can pull (update) our local repo without a "pulling commit"?

Here is the simplified example of the story:

My friend and I had the same copy of the source code from remote repo on our local repo.

Example Source code:

```
<p> This is the title </p>
<p> I love to code </p>
```

Now my friend decided to add another line of code to the original one:

```
<p> Adding important text </p>
```

He then committed and pushed to the remote repo. After that, I pulled from the remote repo. Now I also have what my friend added.

Then my friend decided to remove that line of code :

```
<p> Adding important text </p>
```

Now I have to pull (update) again, but the thing is, because my local has that Added line of code, I am required to make a commit (Merge). Then when I push, that commit is going to be there. This means that there are 2 commits with the same change (my friend's commit and my commit's --with different messages, of course)

My question is, is there a better way to deal with this problem? Is there a way to avoid unnecessary commits? I know we should wait until we really sure about the changes before we push to the remote, but things happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to clean up the commit history, you can use `git reset --hard`.
For example, here is your commit history:

```
commit N+2: "Added important text again"
commit N+1: "Removed important text"
commit N:   "Added important text"
...
```

You would like to make it look like this:

```
commit N: "Added important text"
...
```

Then do the following (where 2 is a number of commits from the last one):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git push --force
```

**Be careful:** using this combination may lead to **code loss** and you won't be able to restore it. By the way, that's all right to have identical changes. At least you don't risk to lose anything.

Comment: So basically, we just revert back to the original commit. This means that we will lose any code that was done within the latest commits just like you mentioned, so I think I should just leave it there. Thank you!